# Playing a video file saved in the app's documents directory

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, ios4, mpmovieplayercontroller

I have a video file saved in my app's local directory in the documents folder. I want to playback the file when the user clicks on the item in an embedded table view I created. My code for playing back the video is as follows:

```
NSString* documentPath = [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) objectAtIndex:0];
NSString* path = [documentPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"DemoRecording.mp4"];
NSURL* movieURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath: path];
[player.view setFrame: self.view.bounds];
[self.view addSubView: player.view];
[player play];
MPMoviePlayerViewController* moviePlayer = [[MPMoviePlayerViewController alloc] initWithContentURL: movieURL];
[self presentMoviePlayerViewControllerAnimated: moviePlayer];
```

The video doesn't play back. The path is correct and the file exists there. 
I know this is a repetitive question. I have referred to these links:
[Playing a Downloaded Video from the Documents Directory with Cocoa-Touch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11549143/playing-a-downloaded-video-from-the-documents-directory-with-cocoa-touch)
[MPMoviePlayer load and play movie saved in app documents](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3945121/mpmovieplayer-load-and-play-movie-saved-in-app-documents)
But couldn't find a definitive answer. 
Please help me out on this one. I am using iOS 5.1.1, if that changes anything.

EDIT:

It does work. I had forgotten to pass the URL to the movie player.

Comment: if you can, use web view to show the file. that's easier

Comment: Where have you passed the `movieURL` to the `player` ?

Comment: You are correct I did not pass the URL to the player. I have edited the code to include that and it works. Sincere apologies.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

you can play Video from Document Directory like this way:-

```
-(IBAction)playVideo
{
    NSURL *vedioURL;
    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];

    NSArray *filePathsArray = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] subpathsOfDirectoryAtPath:documentsDirectory  error:nil];
    NSLog(@"files array %@", filePathsArray);        

    NSString *fullpath;

    for ( NSString *apath in filePathsArray )
    {
        fullpath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:apath];       
        vedioURL =[NSURL fileURLWithPath:fullpath];
    }
    NSLog(@"vurl %@",vedioURL);
    MPMoviePlayerViewController *videoPlayerView = [[MPMoviePlayerViewController alloc] initWithContentURL:vedioURL];
    [self presentMoviePlayerViewControllerAnimated:videoPlayerView];
    [videoPlayerView.moviePlayer play];     
}
```

**NOTE**

> Please note that don't Forget to include requested Framework or connect Delegate

Answer (score 1):

The mistake in you was you missed `/` before DemoRecording.mp4

It should be

```
NSString* path = [documentPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"/DemoRecording.mp4"];
```

Also you are writing `player` statements before declaring it.