# pass recorded video using NSNotificationCenter

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode7, avcapturesession

I have a video recorded output and I want to pass to other tabview controller. Below is my code

```
dispatch_queue_t queue = dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0);
dispatch_async(queue, ^{

    ALAssetsLibrary *assetLibrary = [[ALAssetsLibrary alloc] init];
    [assetLibrary writeVideoAtPathToSavedPhotosAlbum:recordedFile
                                     completionBlock:
     ^(NSURL *assetURL, NSError *error) {

         dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{



             NSString *title;
             NSString *message;

             if (error != nil) {

                 title = @"Failed to save video";
                 message = [error localizedDescription];
             }
             else {
                 title = @"Saved!";
                 message = nil;
             }

             UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:title
                                                             message:message
                                                            delegate:nil
                                                   cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"
                                                   otherButtonTitles:nil];
             [alert show];
      });
     }];
});
}
```

please help me out I am very new to the objective c,send me code please

Comment: recordedFile out put is file:////var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/5421D684-D466-44F1-AEF5-7390598B5647/Documents/2016-07-29-17-00-12-0.MOV

Comment: @Milan  do  you know answer

Comment: is it just that you want to access this video from the path you provided at some other place in your App?

Comment: how to access that video file

Comment: can you please provide me code

Comment: Try to follow this link (http://stackoverflow.com/a/14235008/5012384)

Comment: i already gone through above link.  i want to play the output file in the next view controller

Comment: once your video is in document directory, you can play it in any VC by fetching it.

Comment: ok thanks for you time and time

Comment: I  added the same code   in this link (stackoverflow.com/a/14235008/5012384).the problem i  am getting is the video is appearing and it is closing in a flash

Comment: @SatheeshkumarNaidu if you have correctly write a video file to a path then you can access this file using path anywhere in the app. Check your avplayer code if its closing without playing the file or you can listen the error of AVPlayer simple...

Comment: @pandey_Laxman  this my code  
    NSURL *vedioURL;
    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
    
    NSArray *filePathsArray = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] subpathsOfDirectoryAtPath:documentsDirectory  error:nil];
    NSLog(@"files array %@", filePathsArray);
    
    NSString *fullpath;
    
    for ( NSString *apath in filePathsArray )
    {

Comment: fullpath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:apath];
        vedioURL =[NSURL fileURLWithPath:fullpath];
    }
    NSLog(@"vurl %@",vedioURL);
    MPMoviePlayerViewController *videoPlayerView = [[MPMoviePlayerViewController alloc] initWithContentURL:vedioURL];
    [self presentMoviePlayerViewControllerAnimated:videoPlayerView];
    [videoPlayerView.moviePlayer play];

Comment: @Laxman Due space constrains i divided  commented my code in to 2

Comment: Pass recordedFile to your tableviewController either by block completion or notification

Comment: I want to pass  recorded file to the collection view which is having images.can you please provide me code.

Comment: @laxman   
I want to pass recorded file to the collection view which is having images.if possible can you please provide me code, code helps me lot